# How do database transactions happen in MMORPG's?

Tags: mysql, database, multithreading

I've built an MMORPG that uses a MySQL database to store player related data when the user logs off.

We built in a auto save timer so that all the data of every logged in user is saved to the database every 3 hours.

In doing so we noticed a fatal flaw....

Due to the fact that all our database transactions are sent to a single DB Thread the thread can become backlogged with requests. This produces a login/saving issue. When this happens players unable to login as the login process requires the use of the DB Thread to confirm login credentials. Similarly all save requests are queued to the back of the DB thread schedule. This produces a backlog of requests...

The only solution that I can think of for this is to introduce multiple threads and have 3-4 threads interacting with the database.

However, this opens up a new issue. Since multiple threads are sent DB requests this means that one thread can receive a save request from a player while another DB thread receives a save request from the same player.

For example....
PlayerA Logs In to the game
3 Hours pass & the auto save happens, playerA's data will now be saved.
PlayerA kills a monster and gains experience.
PlayerA logs off, which adds a save request to a DB thread.

Now we have two different save requests queue'd in the database. Assuming they are both assigned to two different DB threads, this could cause the users data to be saved in the wrong order... For example maybe the the thread handling PlayerA's log out save runs first and then the auto save for PlayerA runs after that on a separate thread.... This would cause loss of data (in this case experience).

How do other MMORPG's handle something like this?

Comment: If experience can't go down, only up, then by the sound if it - you require a trigger (on insert or update) that will verify the given experience you are adding isn't lower than current experience the player has. If it is, you can raise an SQLSTATE and no update/insert will occur. I don't know how other companies do it really, but it's logical there are some constraints that won't allow bad values to be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

You need a **database connection pool** if you're not using one already and make sure you're not locking more data than you need. If you are saving how much gold a player has, you don't need to lock the table holding the credentials.

Keeping the order of events in a multi-threaded scenario is not a trivial problem, I suggest using a **message queue**, a single producer per player and a single consumer per player. [This link](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-preserve-order-of-messages.html) shows 2 strategies to keep the order.

A queue is actually important for other reasons. If a save request fails, it would **remain in the queue to retry later**. When dealing with players money and items, you probably want this.

Comment: This doesn't solve the data integrity problem. Also, nearly every language these days maintains a connection pool. The fix is only possible on database level, not by queueing or manually maintaining connection pool. Disallowing inserts if data doesn't match is the way to go, your solution suggests processing data in order through a queue - databases have internal queues, there's no need to reinvent the wheel. A few constraints paired with a few triggers are the fix for the issue of avoiding stale state.

Comment: If there's a connection pool in place, great, but I thought it was important to mention since the OP is moving from a single to multi threaded model and the pool is key for this to work. As for the queue, I agree that only adding a queue won't fix the data integrity, but it's still needed, you need guaranteed delivery in an MMORPG and the database alone won't provide this. Thanks for the feedback, I improved my answer

Comment: You're not wrong in anything you wrote, let's hope it helps OP fix the problem! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Your autosave is deterministic, meaning that you know exactly when the last one occured and when the next one would occur. I would use that somehow, along with the previously suggested idea to add a timestamp. Actually, it might be better to make the updates represent only the increments/decrements along with a user timestamp and calculate the experience upon request ( maybe cache it then)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem in all cases you must not allow users to continue doing stuff before their last database transaction has been successfully committed. Of course that means that the DB has to be very fast -- if it can't keep the request queue below a couple of seconds worth of transactions at most, you simply have to make it faster. More RAM cache, SSDs, the usual MySQL optimization dance. Adding extra logic in the form of triggers etc. isn't going to help in the long run, especially because they can become *really* complicated in the case of inventories and the like.

If on average the system is fast enough but struggling in peaks like when everybody logs in during lunch break, adding something like Redis as a fast cache might help. You'd load the data into Redis when a user logs on (or when they first need a certain piece of data) , remove it when they log off or when it expires, and write changes back to the relational DB as fast as it can keep up.